# How to count unique dates based on multiple or columns

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Any suggestions welcome.

Aims-
I want to create a tally of how many unique dates each person worked, and a separate tally of how many blocks and toilets are built on each day in total and by a person. The work is ongoing, so I think I need a function with an open-ended date, though the start date is hard - 31/5/19

The story so far  - 
I have a writing sheet (Build Check Sheet, link below) with 5 different Work Columns where names are entered for crew who built a block (AI:AM), a Date Column that contains the date a block was finished (AG), and a Qty Column for how many toilets are in each block (F). Each person can appear in any of the 5 columns, and many of the spaces are blank. The date is an integer day, not a time stamp.

So far I've got total blocks built by each person

```
=countif(AI3:AI, name) + ...
```

repeated for each Work Column AI:AM

And the total number of toilets built by each person

```
=sumif(AI3:AI, name, F3:F) +...
```

repeated for each Work Column AI:AM where F column lists the size of each block.

I've tried combining count unique, count if, and count ifs, sumif and sumifs with unique and sort functions but I keep getting invalid formulae, double counting of dates, or result =0. Just making no headway.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lqlGlr-B-MRYwi_WQtDot3U47b3OQ57-hxyR_tEuvSU/edit?usp=drivesdk

Comment: You've asked for suggestions. Perhaps you might outline what you've already tried to do and why it didn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(UNIQUE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(AI3:AM<>"", "♠"&AI3:AM&"♦"&AG3:AG, )),,999^99)),,999^99)), "♠")), "♦")),
 "select Col1,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col2)''", 0))
```

[image]

Comment: You're a legend, thank you player0! I haven't marked answer yet, because I'd forgotten there's a bit more I was looking for. Sorry about the shifting goals. This is amazing and will take me a little while to get my head around :)

Comment: @ciaranhaines not sure whats your new objective... can you explain in more detail?

Comment: Yes. I want to 1. be able to graph the progress- toilets (column F) totals by each day completed in a bar graph (had been thinking to make a table first but still figuring out a function that involves counting or sitting by date) , and 2. figure out how many toilets each person has built by day (again, aiming to graph, but we thinking of calculating a table first so I can understand what's going on).

Comment: how about this: `=QUERY({AG3:AG,F3:F}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col2 is not null and Col1 is not null group by Col1 label sum(Col2)''", 0)` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vMoX.png or perhaps changing sum to count

Comment: player0, you are my hero. Thank you thank you thank you!